# How to access a docker-compose container running with Minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube

I used to setup and run some containers in my local machine with `docker-compose` with the Docker daemon running via Docker Desktop.

I uninstalled Docker Desktop (due to licensing issues) and installed the Docker daemon manually together with Minikube and the qemu driver.

I can successfully run docker on the Minikube VM and I can successfully start containers via docker-compose.

- `minikube ip` returns the IP of the local Kubernetes cluster.
- `minikube ssh` and then pinging the running container (a Postgres image) works.

The container is defined in `docker-compose.yml` as:

```
  my.container:
    container_name: my.container
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    volumes:
      - my.container:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

What I do to start the docker container:

```
$ minikube start
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
$ docker-compose up -d my.app
```

I'm not using minikube to deploy my apps on Kubernetes. I do not have any pods running. (In my understanding) the cluster simply spins up a VM where the docker daemon runs.

Output of `kubectl get services`:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   130.14.93.8  <none>        443/TCP   7d23h
```

**Problem**: I cannot connect to these containers from localhost, nor from anywhere except from within the Minikube VM.

How do I set this up to be able to hit `localhost:5432` with my Postgres client?

Comment: While using minikube with docker you need to check on the below points and have a try accordingly.


       1. Minikube will not be available to the outside world by default, so you must expose it if you want to be able to access it from outside the cluster by following this [official documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes_101/module4/#step-1---create-a-new-service).

Comment: 2. Using minikube service with a tunnel the network is limited if using the Docker driver and the Node IP is not reachable directly. Running a minikube on Linux with the Docker driver will result in no tunnel being created. Follow this [tunneling](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:%7E:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system) into Minikube for accessing it